# How to convert ascii to utf8 with maven

Tags: maven, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I have some generated classes, which are generated with ASCII encoding. But to compile this classes, the classes must be in UTF-8 encoding.

So I need a plugin that converts this classes from ASCII or ISO-8859-1 respectivly to UTF-8.

I tried to use the maven-resources-plugin and the native2ascii-maven-plugin to convert the files. But they didn't what I need.
The maven-resources-plugin can only by configured with one  flag, that is used for reading input and writing output. I always use UTF-8. So it's obviously that it hasn't any effect.

On the other hand the native2ascii-maven-plugin only converts in the wrong direction, namly from UTF-8 to ASCII. But I need to convert the files from ASCII to UTF8.

Are there any other plugins or which plugin solves my problem? Which configuration I have to use? Please provide a definitely working configuration snippet.

Thanks

Comment: If a file contains only ASCII compatible bytes (< 128), it's already UTF-8 encoded, since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: native2ascii does not convert to ASCII as its name confusingly states. Rather it will replace non-latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) characters in a file of the given encoding, with unicode-escaped (`\uXXXX`) UTF-16 code units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, the [AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and Ant's [Copy Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) with its `encoding` and `outputencoding` attributes should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your tip with encoding and outputencoding. Now the AntRun Plugin with CopyTask now does the job.

Comment: This does not provide a "Please provide a definitely working configuration snippet.". I'm trying to solve a similar if not the same issue. How would I configure my ANT plugin?

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. All symbols that can be expressed in ASCII are encoded in the same way in UTF-8.

(I have a feeling that your problem has got to be too trivial to be true. Please edit your question if the case is actually more complex.)

Comment: I believe the question would be how to convert escaped unicode in a latin1 encoded file back to UTF-8 character.