# Converting strings to unicode as part of a maven build

Tags: java, maven, unicode, build

I have some localisation resource files (e.g messages_es.properties) which need to be in unicode in order to display properly in the browser. To avoid having to store unicode and non-unicode* versions of the resource files I'd like to incorporate a convert to unicode task into the maven build. Are there any easy methods/tools for doing this?

## Example

`label.button.loadMoreImages=CARGAR MÁS IMÁGENES` -> `label.button.loadMoreImages=CARGAR M&#193;S IM&#193;GENES`

*much easier to work with when texts change and need re-translating

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330485/how-to-convert-ascii-to-utf8-with-maven

Comment: It'd probably be better if your translators used a proper properties file editor.

Comment: @McDowell - not within my control unfortunately

Comment: Properties files are required to be encoded in ISO-8859-1, so wheresrhys's example is in fact a proper properties file.  Characters below \u0100 don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are quite specific and I doubt you'll find a tool to do what you want. Consider [writing your own Maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html).

First, you must take the properties file and decode the data. Properties files are generally stored in ISO 8859-1, but it is possible to [perform your own character decoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) by providing an `InputStreamReader`.

Next, you want to enumerate and XML-escape the non-ASCII values. [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) provides a type for doing that if you don't want to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

There's simple two ant tasks to convert native to ascii and back that could be arranged as targets like this

```
  <target name="native2ascii">
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}/resources" includes="*.properties" />
    <native2ascii encoding="cp1252" src="${source.dir}/resources" dest="${classes.dir}/resources" includes="*.properties" />
  </target>

  <target name="ascii2native">
    <native2ascii  encoding="cp1252" src="${classes.dir}/resources" dest="${resources.dir}"  includes="*.properties" reverse="true"/>
  </target>
```

That would be easy to adjust to your environment.

Comment: 1) The poster is using Maven (though I realise it is possible to use one from the other) 2) The target must produce XML-escapes; not Java Unicode escapes.

Comment: @McDowell 1) Can't it be integrated into maven? 2) OP asked for "convert to unicode".